# static linking vs include

Tags: c++, static, linker, include

If I made 2 txt code files in c++, one main file and another file for some code for some function.
what's the difference between "statically linking" and "include" the 2nd file ?
and what's best for memory?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  I'd normally suggest tagging your question with the C++ tag, but maybe it is as well you didn't this time — you need to improve your question a bit before it is retagged.  I'm guessing you have `main.cpp` containing something like `extern int other(); int main() { return other(); }` and `sub.cpp` containing `extern int other(); int other() { return 1; }`, and you are debating whether to compile these as two separate files and link them into one program, or to add `#include "sub.cpp"` into `main.cpp` so you only compile one file.

Comment: For the hypothesized example, it really won't make much difference.  The compiler probably can optimize the whole program to `int main(){return 1;}` if it is all in one file (aggressive inlining).  In general, you will have multiple source files being compiled separately and the resulting object files will be linked to create a program.  Get used to that; it is standard.  It also allows for proper separation of duties.  Different files do not need to know about everything that the other files know about.

Comment: Note how my trivial example should have had a header `header.h` containing `extern int other();`, and that header should be included by both `main.cpp` and `sub.cpp` (and the `extern` declarations in the `.cpp` files should be removed).  This helps ensure consistency across files.  This is also typical of bigger programs; it's why you have all the C++ standard headers too.

Comment: The term 'static linking' applies to how libraries are linked into the program.  With static linking, the relevant parts of the libraries are copied into the executable, instead of being loaded as shared libraries or DLLs at runtime.  Whether you use static linking with the one object file or two object file versions of the code is independent of (tangential to) the issue of one vs two object files.